# Verify Digital Signature using groupdocs signatures C#

Tags: c#, digital-signature, groupdocs

I want to verify digital signatures of my customers using groupdocs Signature, here I am using
[This](https://blog.groupdocs.com/2020/10/06/verify-digital-signature-in-documents-using-java/) Link to get proper code, but the problem is when I initialize `GroupDocs.Signature.Signature signature = new Signature("sample_signed.pdf");` I Am getting the error

> CS0234 C# The type or namespace 'Signature' does not exist in the namespace 'GroupDocs.Signature'
> (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My groupdocs version is 19.6, what can I do to verify my digital signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an older version of the API. Please try to use the latest version 21.2 and you won't face this issue. Furthermore, have a look at these [migration notes](https://docs.groupdocs.com/signature/java/migration-notes/).

*Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at GroupDocs.*